# How Can I pass an image file to wp_handle_upload?

Tags: uploads

I have been looking everywhere for this and havent been able to find an answer.

I need to pass a file from the url source to wp_handle_upload. How can I accomplish this?

Thank you

Comment: you may want to check out these:
[`wp_handle_upload()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_handle_upload)[`wp_handle_sideload()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_handle_sideload)[`media_handle_upload()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/media_handle_upload) - [`media_handle_sideload()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/media_handle_sideload])[`media_sideload_image()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/media_sideload_image)

Answer (score 2):

[`wp_handle_upload()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_handle_upload/) is made to handle, well, uploads. It expects upload-related inputs.

To "upload" image from remote URL there is [`media_sideload_image()`](http://queryposts.com/function/media_sideload_image/). Since you actually don't specify type of your file, you might need to tinker some yourself, using this function as an example.

Comment: I am using the js plugin croppic for uploading users avatars. I thought I could use 'wp_handle_upload()' I do know the file type and other details but well, I will try what you suggested.

Comment: I see that function needs a post id. However, I dont want to attach the image to a post. Is there any other function I can use to upload an image from an url?

Comment: @Gixty use `media_sideload_image()` with `0` as post id to not attach image to any post.

Comment: @G.M. thank you both, Now, how can I get the attachement id? Because `media_sideload_image()` only returns the url.

Answer (score 1):

As @Rarst said, most convenient way to handle an external upload and create the related attachment post is use [`media_sideload_image()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_handle_upload/), this function:

- Download the url
- Verify if it is a valid a image and if so
- create the attachment post
- attach this attachment to a specific post whose id is passed as argument
- return the `img` html tag for the image

However, sometimes one may want just access to attachment post id and is not interested in attache the attachment to any post, in this case WordPress has no built-in function, so the most convenient way is copy part of core from `media_sideload_image()` and part of `media_handle_sideload()`:

```
 function custom_media_sideload_image( $image_url = '', $post_id = false  ) {
   require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php';
   $tmp = download_url( $image_url );
   // Set variables for storage
   // fix file filename for query strings
   preg_match( '/[^\?]+\.(jpe?g|jpe|gif|png)\b/i', $image_url, $matches );
   $file_array['name'] = basename($matches[0]);
   $file_array['tmp_name'] = $tmp;
   // If error storing temporarily, unlink
   if ( is_wp_error( $tmp ) ) {
    @unlink($file_array['tmp_name']);
    $file_array['tmp_name'] = '';
   }
   $time = current_time( 'mysql' );
   $file = wp_handle_sideload( $file_array, array('test_form'=>false), $time );
   if ( isset($file['error']) ) {
    return new WP_Error( 'upload_error', $file['error'] );
   }
   $url = $file['url'];
   $type = $file['type'];
   $file = $file['file'];
   $title = preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename($file) );
   $parent = (int) absint( $post_id ) > 0 ? absint($post_id) : 0;
   $attachment = array(
     'post_mime_type' => $type,
     'guid' => $url,
     'post_parent' => $parent,
     'post_title' => $title,
     'post_content' => '',
   );
   $id = wp_insert_attachment($attachment, $file, $parent);
   if ( !is_wp_error($id) ) {
    require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php'; 
    $data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $id, $file );
    wp_update_attachment_metadata( $id, $data );
  }  
  return $id;
}
```

This function act as `media_sideload_image()` but return the attachment id, or a `WP_Error` if something goes wrong.

It takes an optional argument `$post_id` to attach media to a specific post/page, but if not passed, the attachemnt post is created but not attached to any post.