# Make custom thumbnail size image in media_sideload_image function

Tags: uploads, media

I am using customize `media_sideload_image` just as provided in [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/141172/how-can-i-pass-an-image-file-to-wp-handle-upload) by @G.M.

Now I want to create different sizes of images other than which WP default uses.

Please provide suggestion

Comment: I am using like   $image = media_sideload_image($url, $post_id);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this in your functions file.

```
    add_image_size( 'category-thumb', 300 ); // 300 pixels wide (and unlimited height)
    add_image_size( 'homepage-thumb', 220, 180, true ); // (cropped)
```

Then you can do something like this to give your custom size a certain name in the Admin area.

```
add_filter( 'image_size_names_choose', 'my_custom_sizes' );

function my_custom_sizes( $sizes ) {
    return array_merge( $sizes, array(
        'your-custom-size' => __( 'Your Custom Size Name' ),
    ) );
}
```

More info can be found [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size) and [here.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/set_post_thumbnail_size)